# Morbo server works only after constant refresh

Tags: ajax, perl, mojolicious

I am developing a web application with Mojolicious. The morbo development server is a wonderful thing that works great, but once I start returning complicated hashes on the stack and then rendering a webpage, the morbo server will start to act funny. In my browser, if I navigate to one of those webpages that use a complicated hash, the browser will tell me that the connection has been reset. I have to refresh about 10-12 times before the page will load.

For example:

The code below shows one of my app controllers. It simply gets a json object from an AJAX request, and then returns a different json object. It works fine, except that the browser demands to be refreshed a thousand times before it will load.

```
package MyApp::Controller::Library;
use Mojo::Base 'Mojolicious::Controller';

use Mojo::Asset::File;
use MyApp::Model::Generate;
use MyApp::Model::Database;
use MyApp::Model::IpDatabase;
use Mojo::JSON qw(decode_json);

# Receives a json object from an AJAX request and
# sends the necessary information back to be
# displayed in a table.
sub list_ajax_catch {
    my $self = shift;

    my $json  = $self->param('data');
    my $input = decode_json $json;

    $self->render(
        json => {
            "Object A" => {
                "name"        => "Object A's Name",
                "description" => "A Description for Object A",
                "height"      => "10",
                "width"       => "5",
            }
        }
    );
}

1;
```

The problem is not limited to this instance. It seems that anytime there is a lot of processing on the server, the browser has troubles resetting. It doesn't matter what browser, I've tried Chrome, IE, Firefox, and others (on multiple computers). It doesn't matter if I'm not even sending or receiving data back and forth from the html to the app. All that seems to trigger it is if there is any amount of processing in my web app that is more than just rendering templates, BUT if I am running Hypnotoad, everything is fine.

This example is not one that requires a lot of processing, but it does cause the browser to reset, and as you can see, it shouldn't take long to run or freeze anything up. I thought the problem was a timeout issue, but by default, timeout doesn't happen until after 15 seconds, so it can't be that.

Comment: That does not look like a problem in your code. Check the logs on a server side, if you find anything interesting there, please update the question. Can it just hit some memory limits (especially if you run the server on a VPS)?

Comment: Yeah, I'll see what I can find. Do you have any recommendations on where I can find those logs?

Comment: The browser behaviour your describing sounds like a redirect loop.

Comment: The logs were easy to find, sorry about that. Yes, I looked at them and they don't show anything helpful. After a failure this is what I got (see below):

Comment: `[Fri Oct 31 09:05:51 2014] [debug] GET "/librarygrid".
[Fri Oct 31 09:05:51 2014] [debug] Routing to controller "IpdmWeb::Controller::Library" and action "gen_library_grid".
[Fri Oct 31 09:05:53 2014] [debug] Rendering template "librarygrid.html.ep".
[Fri Oct 31 09:05:53 2014] [debug] Rendering template "layouts/default.html.ep".
[Fri Oct 31 09:05:53 2014] [debug] 200 OK (1.525676s, 0.655/s).
[Fri Oct 31 09:06:21 2014] [debug] GET "/librarygrid".`

Comment: I have tried looking into my redirects, but everything seems to be fine. Like I said, it works fine with Hypnotoad, just not Morbo.

Comment: Thanks @harvey for your help. Just your suggestion of 'redirect loop' helped narrow down a lot of my troubleshooting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured out the problem! This has been an issue for me for over a month now and I am so glad that it is working again. My problem was that when I started the morbo development server, I used the following command:

```
morbo -w ~/web_dev/my_app script/my_app
```

The -w allows me to watch a directory for changes so that I don't have to restart the app each time I changed some of my JavaScript files. My problem was that the directory I watched also contained my log files. So each time I went to my webpage, the logs would change and the server would restart.

Comment: ..and also if you are OUT-writing files. Took me half a day to figure that out.